# UI-View not rendering template on localhost running in Apache but perfectly rendering when served directly from Filesystem

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, angular-ui-router

I am using UI Router for state operations in AngularJS 1.6.5.
The UI-View is not rendering the supplied template when running through XAMPP with Apache whereas if it is served directly through filesystem without any web server it works and renders the template perfectly.

Below is the script file---

**Main Index Page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="ResponseIo">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>ResponseIo Management Interface</title>
</head>
<body>

    <ui-view></ui-view>

    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**App.JS**

```
var ResponseIo = angular.module("ResponseIo", ["ui.router"]);
ResponseIo.config(["$stateProvider", function ($stateProvider) {
    var homeState = {
        name: "home",
        url: "/",
        template: "<p>I am at home</p>"
    };
    var same = {
        name: "cat",
        url: "/cat",
        template: "I am at home"
    }
    $stateProvider.state(homeState);
    $stateProvider.state(same);
}]);
```